# React Hook error in array handing in useEffect() and setState does not set the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having two problems in this code. The first is in the second useEffect. For the reason that I don't understand the useEffect stops working every now and then and causes an error "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase'". Removing the toLowerCase does not solve the problem, but the whole array handling seems to be impossible at that time.

The other problem is in the function addName. setNewName does not set newName. That one I've tried in various kinds of forms, such as setNewName(...newName, {name: '', number: ''}), setNewName('') inside .then and else as well as outside else.

...

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Filter from './components/Filter'
import PersonForm from './components/PersonForm'
import Persons from './components/Persons'
import personService from './services/person'


const App = () => {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState([])
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState({name: '', number: ''})
  const [filteredPerson, setFilteredPerson] = useState([''])
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    personService
      .getAll()
      .then(initialPersons => {
        setPerson(initialPersons)
      })
  }, [])


  useEffect( () => { 
    const results = person.filter( p =>
      p.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) )
    
    setFilteredPerson(results)
  },[person,filteredPerson] )


  const addName = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault() 
    const nameObject = {
      name: newName.name,
      number: newName.number
    }
  
    if (person.some(p => p.name === newName.name)  
    ) {
      window.alert(`${newName.name} is already added to phonebook`)    
    }
    else { 
      personService
      .create(nameObject)
      .then(returnedPerson => {
        setPerson(person.concat(returnedPerson))
        setNewName({name: '', number: ''})                  
      })
      
      console.log('newName', newName.name )           
    }  
  }

  const handleAddPerson = (event) => {
    console.log('event.target.name ', event.target.name) 
    console.log('event.target.value ', event.target.value)
    setNewName({...newName,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }

  const handleSearchTerm = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div >
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <Filter searchTerm={searchTerm} onChange={handleSearchTerm} /> 

      <h3>Add a new</h3>  
      <PersonForm onSubmit={addName} onChange={handleAddPerson} />
      
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      <Persons list={filteredPerson} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

...

```
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/persons'

const getAll = () => {
    const request = axios.get(baseUrl)
    return request.then(response => response.data)
}

const create = newObject => {
    const request = axios.post(baseUrl, newObject)
    return request.then(response => response.data)
}

const update = (id, newObject) => {
    const request = axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, newObject)
    return request.then(response => response.data)
}

/*const updater = {
    getAll,
    create,
    update
}*/

export default {
    getAll,
    create,
    update
}
```

Comment: If you are getting errors like "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined” then that means that some or all elements of your person array are not objects with a name property.  Check your API results and make sure that returnedPerson and initialPersons are the data structures that you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

Use async await in your `personService` so you can return response instead of `return request.then(...)` something like:

```js
const getAll = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(baseUrl);
  return response;
}
```

After that you can do as follows in your `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const response = await personService.getAll();
    if (response.status === 200) {
      setPerson(response.data);
      const filtered = response.data.filter(item =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
      );
      setFilteredPerson([...filtered]);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

Comment: I couldn't make this work. Instead I ended into never ending loop

Comment: Try to handle filter inside IIFE and `setFilteredPerson`